# React - Add Active class to list item react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im learning now the **ReactJS** and I read a lot of topics about this article, but I can't find a right solution for my problem.

I want to add a `active` class to `li` item not `a`, like

```
<li class="active"><a href="">Item</a></li>
```

not

```
<li><a href="" class="active">Item</a></li>
```

This is my `reactJS` code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Content = () => (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
        <div className="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/app">Wallets</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/backup">Backup</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/keys">Private keys</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/security">Security</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" target="_blank">How it works</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/app" component={App} />
                <Route path="/backup" component={Backup} />
                <Route path="/keys" component={Keys} />
                <Route path="/security" component={Security} />
                <Redirect to="/app" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

...

export default Content;
```

Comment: Note that this question is about adding dynamic classNames to the **<li>** tags, not the **<a>** tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NavLink, it has a property for the active Links:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

After:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <NavLink to="YOUR_ROUTE" exact activeClassName="link-active">
   { YOUR_CONTENT }
  </NavLink>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Now your links which are actives will have link-active class name.

Comment: but I need also `li` items

Comment: Its generate only a `<a href=""...`, without `li`

Comment: Do you need <a href=""... and inside a li ?

Answer (score 0):

activeClassName
The className a  receives when its route is active. No active class by default.

> https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html